# Vscode not buffering python print

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, input, printing

For example if I run this code in integrated vscode terminal:

```
for i in range(2):
    a = input()
    print(a)
```

And I paste the following:

```
a
b
```

The console will display:

```
a
a
b
b
```

I want the console to display (without changing the code):

```
a
b
a
b
```

Note: above is the typical behaviour when running python script from linux terminal or IDLE, but not in vscode. I believe the issue is with the vscode console not buffering the prints.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that kind of output you can use list comprehension to store the two letters in a list. Right now `a` and `b` are shown. So if we print the list, we will get the same pattern.

```
inputs = [input() for i in range(2)]
print('\n'.join(inputs))
```

output

```
a
b
a
b
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to modify the behavior of vscode console to behave like linux terminal or IDLE. I don't wanna have to save all values to array before printing.

Answer (score 0):

```
myLetters=[]
for i in range(2):
    a = input()
    myLetters.append(a)
print(myLetters[0] + "\n"+  myLetters[1])
```